# Session keeps timing out

Tags: asp.net, session-state

My session keeps timing out in just a few minutes even though I've specified a 200 minute expiry.

In my web.config I've set the timeout for the forms and the sessionState. I've looked at some other similar questions on Stack Overflow but still can't suss this.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" defaultUrl="~/secure/Default.aspx"
    timeout="180"/>      
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="200" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your application gets recycled?

This can be caused by changing web.config files, the contents of the bin folder or by deleting (temp) folders in your application. (and probably there exist other reasons as well)

Comment: IIS will also recycle applications based on the configuration for the application pool. There are settings to reset at a particular time, after a certain amount of time has elapsed, and also after a certain number of requests. I would keep at your app pool settings first to rule out application recycling.

Comment: Do you think an inactive timeout in IIS set to 20 minutes would have the same affect?

Answer (score 0):

use the following line in code behind of aspx page:

**Session.Timeout = 180;**

This line should be written in Page_Load event and at the top of Page Load Event.

I hope this answer may help you.